# Most efficient way to find median of three integers

Tags: c#, median

Which the most effecient way to find a median of three integer number without using an array like the example below:

```
int[] median = {int a, int b,int c};
Array.Sort(median); 

int medianValue = median[1];
```

Comment: Use two `if` statements that mimic sorting.

Comment: You don't need to worry about efficiency if your set is always restricted to just 3 elements.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems do you have with your implementation?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Can you please share with us the solution with 2 IFs?

Comment: @StenPetrov: undelete your post, you had it with a small error on your second statement (which I edited).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel as you can see in my comments on the accepted answer there's a better solution. I also found the error so I deleted my answer

Comment: Side note: finding the efficient way of doing something is a loaded question. When using a [3GL language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-generation_programming_language) like C# you are going to utilizes the libraries i.e. Framework that is built in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The fastest way I know of is to use

`max(min(a, b), min(max(a, b), c))`

I'm trusting that C# has optimisations for `min` and `max` taking two arguments. This will be quicker than taking `if` statements due to branching.

There are other tricks: you can implement min and max using XOR and < but I doubt that has any benefits on modern architectures.

Comment: @StenPetrov: Quite possibly you're correct. My optimisation comes from the C and C++ worlds where a modern chipset would certainly have fast implementations of `min` and `max` and the compiler would exploit that.

Comment: turns out you're correct in C# as well. 10 million executions test in LINQPad: 3-IF chain executes with the same speed as min/max (+/1 1%) when compiler optimizations are OFF. When optimizations are ON the min/max executes about 50+% faster. Please edit something in your answer so I can reverse my vote.

Comment: Note this min/max solution will (correctly) return NaN should any of the operands be NaN, making it the preferred solution for floating point. (The question is about integers but I just *know* someone will copy naive if/else solutions for floating point and live to regret it.)

Answer (score 1):

```
    int Median(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        if ((num2 < num1 && num1 < num3) || (num2 > num1 && num1 > num3))
        {
            return num1;
        }

        if ((num1 < num2 && num2 < num3) || (num1 > num2 && num2 > num3))
        {
            return num2;
        }

        return num3;
    }
```